# 500 POST internal server error ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I just started to learn Ajax.I have situation in which when i call the ajax i have got this in my console.

> POST http://server1/cmsgovtsite/admin/announcement/remove_attachment 500 (Internal Server Error)

I am using the codeigniter platform. I have referred to many solutions on Stack Overflow, but I haven't been able to solve this.

```
function remove(attachment_id) {                            
    var baseurl = $('#base').val();
    //alert(baseurl);
    //alert(attachment_id);

    $.ajax({
        url: baseurl + "admin/announcement/remove_attachment",
        // async: false,
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            attachment_id: attachment_id
        },
        datatype: "json",
        success: function(result) {
            $('#result1').html(result);
        }
    })
}
```

```php
function remove_attachment() 
{
    // $this->new_announcement();
    // echo sdfsdfdfg;
    $id = $this->input->post('attachment_id');
    echo 'hello'.$id;
    $this->load->model('announcement_model');
    // $data['ajax_req'] = TRUE;
    $this->announcement_model->changestatus($id);
    // $this->load->view('announcement_edit',$data);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn pull-right" type="button" onclick="remove(<?php echo $getannouncementfile['id'] ?>)">
    <i class="fa fa-minus-circle fa-1x" aria-hidden="true" title="Add more document" alt="Add more documents"/></i> 
    Remove Attachment
</button>
```

And i have to add that the error only happens when i load my model

Comment: Your code working without ajax ?

Comment: what is value of `alert(baseurl);`?

Comment: @AlexandrMalyita-yes it's working fine without ajax

Comment: @HikmatSijapati-That's just alerting my baseurl

Comment: how have you manage routes.`admin/announcement/remove_attachment`.If you have not manage routes then third arguments in url is taken as function parameter.

Comment: If you use chrome dev tools you can actually see the underlaying error which would be what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by editing the controller function and not by calling the model.
Now my controller is as follows

```
function remove_attachment() {

$id=$this->input->post('attachment_id');
$data=array(
            'status'    => '0',                                                                              );
$this->db->where('id',$id);
$this->db->update('tb_announcements_file',$data);
 //echo'One record deleted Successfully';
 exit;

}
```

Thanks to everyone who had helped me..

Answer (score 2):

Check ensure your .htaccess or Change your url
like below

```
url: baseurl + "index.php/admin/announcement/remove_attachment",
```

Comment: change you url like url: baseurl + "index.php/admin/announcement/remove_attachment",

Comment: @ Safiul Alam Najel-nothing happened.

Comment: Please go to config.php then change it. config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;

Comment: can u get your base url correclty using id in jquery? and your controller path is correct?i mean is it like: application->controller->admin->announcement

Comment: yes i have echoed the announcement id which i am passing through the ajax in the controller

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<?php echo $getannouncementfile['id'] ?>` to `<?php echo $getannouncementfile['id']; ?>`

**;**

Comment: Can you access error log? And please post **full** contents of php file

Answer (score 0):

try this code with mozilla firefox browser so in inspect panel you will get full details with request and response data and also get where you wrong in your code

check in your config file if csrf_protection is true then do it false and then try it

Comment: when you get full path in console so copy that and and run in url if you get output then  do false your csrf_protection mode in config file